# HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway Configuring IIS 7 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am a newbie to Stack Overflow (first post), but really see the use of this website.

I'm stumped.  We are trying to setup IIS 7.0 to run with WinPython 2.7 on a Windows 7 machine.

I am an IIS newb, but veteran Python user.  IIS 7 can NOT find a library, which python finds, and executes, perfectly when ran on it's own.  When executed via IIS, the script fails with a traceback, and IIS returns the 502.2.

I found this thread http://forums.iis.net/p/1209465/2073173.aspx?HTTP+Error+502+2+Bad+Gateway+Frustrations but the advised solution is simply another troubleshooting suggestion.

I found IIS's description (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942057) of the error helpful, but futile.

I found Python's start-up options/parameters helpful (http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html), but futile.

I found IIS's advice for configuring Python helpful (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494, but (questionably?) incomplete.

This thread on manually defining an alternate bin folder (http://forums.asp.net/t/1303052.aspx?Tell+IIS+to+load+dll+from+another+directory+not+Bin+web+config+) might be where my solution lies, but I don't think it is because of the fact that this all worked on 2.6 without doing that to IIS.

IIS seems to allow python to import any module that is just a python script.  As soon as it gets to a *.pyd (basically just python's version of a dll file) file, it screams.  I'm no pro when it comes to DLLs and windows environments, but wouldn't IIS have to have paths to a bin folder of some kind? Do I have to manually edit them, as discussed in the last link above?

**ACTUAL ERROR Details below for DLL failed Load:**

The Error :

> " HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway The specified CGI application
>   misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The
>   headers it did return are "Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "\estorage.equitable.int\riskmgmt\Quants\web\LinksPage.py", line 2,
>   in  import pyweb File
>   "\estorage.equitable.int\riskmgmt\Quants\Common2014\Python\pyweb__init__.py",
>   line 5, in  from core import * File
>   "\estorage.equitable.int\riskmgmt\Quants\Common2014\Python\pyweb\core.py",
>   line 2, in  from pylib import pgdb File
>   "\estorage.equitable.int\riskmgmt\Quants\Common2014\Python\pylib\pgdb.py",
>   line 8, in  from scikits import timeseries as ts File
>   "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2-20140401\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\scikits.timeseries-0.91.3-py2.7-win32.egg\scikits\timeseries__init__.py",
>   line 13, in  import const File
>   "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2-20140401\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\scikits.timeseries-0.91.3-py2.7-win32.egg\scikits\timeseries\const.py",
>   line 79, in  from cseries import freq_constants ImportError:
>   DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. ".

I'm confident that the python environment is configured properly, as the script runs from the same executable (python.exe) via a command line.  I'm thinking that I don't have IIS configured properly, for the new Python 2.7 install.  The same script worked yesterday, on IIS and python 2.6.  But during our upgrade from 2.6 to 2.7, a bunch of PATH and PYTHONPATH parameters all changed, plus we went from ActivePython to WinPython.  WinPython is "registered" on the machine.

What I've tried

- confirming python's sys.path is as expected at run-time in both IIS and command line - it is.
- using the module from python command line.
- recompiling the failing module using two different compilers (ming32 and VS2008).
- putting duplicates of my new 2.7 modules in the old python26 folder.
- pulling out lots of hair and other hacky stuff.

My next step, is to post this same message on a python forum.  If anybody can advise on a good one for python-IIS related challenges, that would be appreciated.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got this 502.2 error when doing a clean installation of PHP 5.5 in Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.

It turns out PHP is a Visual C++ application which needs the library MSVCR110.dll in order to run properly.  My computer does not have Visual Studio 2012 installed and thus it does not have this file.  I got my problem solved by installing the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#

Answer (score 0):

(Note: jc77 is my associate, and I'm actually the OP, as this was an x-post from IIS forums.)

We solved the problem.

tl,dr; portable python + sloppy/rookie compiling = strange behaviour + frustrations.

Bottom line, compile properly. For scikits.timeseries, using ming32 everything will walk, talk, and sound like it works in Spyder.exe, but not in python.exe.  You have to use VS2008, if you want it to work in both.

More Info:

Winpython (as well as others) presents itself as identical to any other python installations, if you "register" the installation.  It works great, 99% of the time.  We learned the hard way, that "Winpython Interpreter.exe" and "python.exe" provided in the install are in fact different. Can't explain why, but the two executables gave different behavior.  We were doing all our testing in Spyder, which must use "winpython interpreter.exe".  The module which IIS couldn't find, would import and run no problem in Spyder.  Then, in IIS, using python.exe, the module wouldn't import.  We were operating on the assumption that the IDE would use python.exe, and that the stack was identical.  As, 99% of the time, they appear to be.  The way we were compiling scikits worked in winpython interpreter.exe.  We were making a rookie mistake when compiling scikits, but it went un-noticed because it was working fine in our IDE (Spyder).

I'm adding these keywords for others : Anybody else who receives errors like this is likely using a portable python installation AND not compiling something properly.  Winpython, Portable Python, eGenix, [and possibly?] Active State and Enthought Canopy.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to configure CGI to run Perl in Windows 8.1, I had HTTP Error 502.2, but then I read loste's post and solved the problem. I had previously installed both Perl64 and Strawberry Perl. Although the IIS EventHandler pointed to only the Perl64 directory, both directories appeared in my Windows PATH variable. I prefer Strawberry Perl, so I changed the EventHandler to point to the Strawberry Perl directory and deleted the paths to Perl64 from the Windows PATH variable to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Hello Python World!")
```

You must specify the type of document